# Set value of data frame new field equal to another field based on condition on a third field in R

Tags: r, dataframe

If I want to add a field to a given data frame and setting it equal to an existing field in the same data frame based on a condition on a different (existing) field.

I know this works:

```
is.even <- function(x) x %% 2 == 0

df <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
                b = c("A","B","C","D","E","F"))

df$test[is.even(df$a)] <- as.character(df[is.even(df$a), "b"])

> df
  a b test
1 1 A   NA
2 2 B    B
3 3 C   NA
4 4 D    D
5 5 E   NA
6 6 F    F
```

But I have this feeling it can be done a lot better than this.

Comment: Look up `ifelse`; that should be exactly what you want.

Comment: I will elaborate the @shreyasgm 's suggestion: `df$test <- ifelse(is.even(df$a),as.character(df$b),NA)`

Answer (score 2):

Using `data.table` it's quite easy

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(a = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
                b = c("A","B","C","D","E","F"))

dt[is.even(a), test := b]

> dt
   a b test
1: 1 A   NA
2: 2 B    B
3: 3 C   NA
4: 4 D    D
5: 5 E   NA
6: 6 F    F
```

Comment: One extra reason to start learning to use `data.table` properly, I guess. It looks far more elegant than the (legit) `ifelse` solution. Thanks.

Comment: I greatly prefer data.table to regular data.frames, both for syntax reasons as well as performance. If you think the answer adequately addresses your question, please consider accepting it.